# Rscript Not Starting httpuv Server

Tags: r, ubuntu, rscript, httpuv

I am attempting to start a server using `startServer()` from the `httpuv` package through Rscript on Ubuntu 20.04. The server will bind to the port if I run `create_server.R` from RStudio or if I run from the command line R interface, but when I try:

```
Rscript create_server.R > outfile.Rout
```

it appears as if the file is executed but the port is not bound and the server is not created.

In the R interface, however, the following will run and bind the port:

`source('create_server.R')`

Does anyone know why running the script using Rscript isn't working or how to launch a persistent httpuv server from the terminal?

The contents of the `.Rout` file say it was started:

```
<WebServer>
  Inherits from: <Server>
  Public:
    getHost: function () 
    getPort: function () 
    getStaticPathOptions: function () 
    getStaticPaths: function () 
    initialize: function (host, port, app, quiet = FALSE) 
    isRunning: function () 
    removeStaticPath: function (path) 
    setStaticPath: function (..., .list = NULL) 
    setStaticPathOption: function (..., .list = NULL) 
    stop: function () 
  Private:
    appWrapper: AppWrapper, R6
    handle: 140156258489016
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port: 5001
    running: TRUE
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have to use `runServer()` rather than `startServer()` if you are hoping to run using Rscript.